# Why is constness not enforced for pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, transitive-const

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
public:

    void nonConstFun()
    {

    }
};

class B
{
private:

    A a_;
    A * pA_;

public:

    void fun() const
    {
        pA_->nonConstFun();
        //a_.nonConstFun(); // Gives const related error
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.fun();
}
```

Here I am expecting the compiler to fail the compilation for lack of constness  for calling `A::nonConstFun()` inside `B::fun()` irrespective of the type of A object.

However the compiler complains for the object, but not for the pointer. Why?
I am using VS2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: a const member function means it will not change the internal state of this object, while what the object has a reference to might be changed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It *is* enforced.

If you try changing the pointer, the compiler will not let you.

The thing that the pointer points to, however, is a different conversation.

Remember, `T* const` and `T const*` are not the same thing!

You can protect that by either actually making it `A const*`, or simply by writing your function in the manner that is appropriate.

Comment: I often find that tools like [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) are useful for making sure that I'm reading the `const` the same way that the compiler is reading it.

Comment: @bta For more complex types that is certainly helpful, although generally you want to avoid those types or at least spell them in a modern & clear way (make aliases, and do it with `using` not `typedef`!). For simple cases like this you should be able to read it instinctively. Remember, `const` applies to the left, unless there's nothing there in which case it applies to the right.

Comment: I think it is not nice that you can essentially change the state of a const object if it has pointer members. [std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) seems to help fix that.

Answer (score 55):

The other answers explain the `T* const` vs `T const *` which is what is happening. But it is important to understand the implication of this beyond just the mere syntax.

When you have a `T*` inside a structure the pointer is inside the object (part of the layout of the objet), but the pointed object is physically outside of the structure. That is why a const object with a `T*` member is not allowed to modify the pointer, but it is allowed to modify the pointed object - because physically the pointed object is outside the enclosing object.

And it is up to the programmer to decide if the pointed object is **logically** part of the enclosing object (and as such should share constness with the enclosing) or if it is logically an external entity. Examples of former include `std::vector`, `std::string`. Examples of the latter include `std::span`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`. As you can see both designs are usefull.

The shortcoming of C++ is that it doesn't offer an easy way to express a logical constness as stated above (what you actually expected from your code).

This is known and for this exact purpose there is an experimental class which is not yet standard [`propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

> std::experimental::propagate_const is a const-propagating wrapper for
> pointers and pointer-like objects. It treats the wrapped pointer as a
> pointer to const when accessed through a const access path, hence the
> name.

```
struct B
{
    A a_;
    std::experimental::propagate_const<A *> pA_;

   void fun()
    {
        pA_->nonConstFun(); // OK
    }
    void fun() const
    {
        // pA_->nonConstFun(); // compilation error
    }
};
```